# Reset Modified Date for Site Contents App Tiles after CU

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sub-site, last-modified-date

As most of you know when you go to site contents and look at your Apps(lists/libraries) they all have a dynamic "Modified" date stamp that is dynamically pointing to the last modified item within the App. Where I work we have a 2013 on prem farm and when we deploy a cumulative update (CU) all the tiles on our sites are reset to the date of when the CU was deployed. The last modified information is retained at the item level but the App tiles within site contents get all goofed up, does anyone know of a PowerShell script or way to reset this sort of thing?

Example App modified date:

[image]

Note this is corrected when an item within the app is updated, however untouched areas and sub sites have incorrect dates. Thank you in advance for your ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Because the previous Modified date isn't saved, there would be no way to revert this date without previously capturing that date across all objects. Do you plan to do this, or do you simply want to set each object to a static date that you've defined?

Comment: Oh our farm is quite large so there would not be an easy way to do this. I just wanted to learn more about it and see if others have the same issue. One day I found a post where someone discovered and solved this issue for SharePoint Online. http://sympmarc.com/2016/07/07/dear-microsoft-please-make-modified-dates-in-site-contents-reflect-content-or-structure-changes-only-again/ I was wondering if there was a fix or solution for on prem sites.

Comment: I'm unsure if newer CUs have resolved this in 2013, but at the very least it is a known issue.